# how can i store last 100 ip addresses who visited my website?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ip

i have a variable say 'ip' which displays the current ip of a visitor who visits my website. Also, every time a new user opens my website, the value of ip gets changed. i need to store first 100 ip addresses who visits my website in an array containing 100 elements so that i can use them for comparison later on using java script. Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are going to need some server-side file or database to to the information. Or you could use the web server logs but the only downside of this is that the web server records every access i.e. html, image, javascript and stylesheet requested for each page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as i said i have already got a variable which shows the ip address of the user who visits my website every time. So i think server is not required, all i need is a loop or something containing an array which will record the last 100 visits only and as soon as it grows it dumps the old values. and yes i need it in javascript only please.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. You must have a `PHP-enabled` server for this to work. The `ip.txt` data file will create itself, and it will appear in the same folder as the page it is included in.

Put this in the top of your website PHP file..

```
<?php
$file = "./ip.txt";
$date   = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$ip     = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];  
$write =  "Date = ".$date." :>IP = ".$ip."|";
file_put_contents($file, $write, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

This is the page to read the IP and date, or you could simply open it with a text editor.

```
The read_ip.php file...
<?php
$read_ip = './ip.txt';
$doc = file_get_contents($read_ip);
$ip_data = explode("|",$doc);
$i = 0;
foreach($ip_data as $data){
$i++;
echo 'row '.$i.':> '.$data.'<br />';
}
?>
```

Simple and straightforward. MySql or any other database system is not required... the .TXT file IS your database. I hope you find this of use.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i got your idea but just 1 thing, how this will find the ip address of the visitor who visits my site and also how can i compare to different ip address values. i need this to create a poll in which 1 person cannot visit again if it is in the array of last 100 visits. so if it would be in javascript then i can use it quite easily. also, my variable which detects the ip address of the visitor is in javascipt only.